# BigQuery: Array<string> field with WriteToBigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm creating a Google Dataflow template in Python:

```
query = "#standardSQL" +  """
SELECT
  Frame.Serial,
  Frame.Fecha,
  Frame.Longitud,
  Frame.Latitud,
  ARRAY_AGG (CONCAT (ID, '-', Valor) ORDER BY ID) AS Resumen
FROM <...>


TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Serial:STRING,Fecha:DATETIME,Longitud:STRING,Latitud:STRING,Resumen:STRING'

| 'Read from BQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query,dataset="xxx",use_standard_sql=True))

| 'Write transform to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery('table',TABLE_SCHEMA)
```

---

### The problem

This fails due Resumen field is an Array:

> Array specified for non-repeated field.

---

### What I tested

1. Create the table directly in BigQuery UI with the sentence:

   `CREATE TABLE test (Resumen ARRAY<STRING>)`

   This works. The table is created with:

   - Type: `string`
   - Mode: `Repeated`
2. Change the TABLE_SCHEMA and run the pipeline:

   `TABLE_SCHEMA ='Serial:STRING,Fecha:DATETIME,Longitud:STRING,Latitud:STRING,Resumen:ARRAY<STRING>'`

   With the error:

   ```
   "Invalid value for: ARRAY\u003cSTRING\u003e is not a valid value".
   ```

---

How it should be the `TABLE_SCHEMA` to create the table and use with `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like repeated or nested fields are not supported if you specify a BQ schema in a single string: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#creating-a-table-schema

You will need to describe your schema explicitly and set the field mode to `repeated`: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/bigquery_schema.py#L95

```
# A repeated field.
children_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
children_schema.name = 'children'
children_schema.type = 'string'
children_schema.mode = 'repeated'
table_schema.fields.append(children_schema)
```